# Calling a few [UIVIew setFrame:] in a row doesn't execute all of them

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I've a strange problem with sliding in a `UIView` into another one while sliding out the other content of the view.

This is the code:

```
- (void)moveAddStudentViewIntoSuperView
{
     CGRect viewFrame1 = self.viewThatShoudlDisappear1.frame;
     CGRect viewFrame2 = self.viewThatShoudlDisappear2.frame;
     CGRect newFrame = self.viewControllerThatshouldAppear.view.frame;

     viewFrame1.origin.x = -300;
     viewFrame2.origin.x = -300;
     newStudentFrame.origin.x = 0;

     NSLog(@"\n 1: %@ \n 2: %@ \n 3: %@", self.viewThatShoudlDisappear1, self.viewThatShoudlDisappear2, self.viewControllerThatshouldAppear.view);

     [self.viewThatShoudlDisappear1 setFrame:viewFrame1];
     [self.viewThatShoudlDisappear2 setFrame:viewFrame2];
     [self.viewControllerThatshouldAppear.view setFrame:newFrame];

     NSLog(@"\n 1: %@ \n 2: %@ \n 3: %@", self.viewThatShoudlDisappear1, self.viewThatShoudlDisappear2, self.viewControllerThatshouldAppear.view);

}
```

(Usually I'd do the `setFrame`s in a `UIView` animation but it doesn't matter for this example as it doesn't work anyway)

What happens is that the view that should slide in or rather is now located at `(0,0)` appears but the other views dont move away. And are still displayed under the new view.

What is strange, is that the log outputs that all views are in the correct position. `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` between the `setFrame` calls doesn't change anything either and even more interesting is that if I remove the `setFrame` from the new view the views that should disappear do actually disappear correctly.

Comment: Obviously I wasn't that concentrated when I wrote this. The code example should be correct now. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried asking for them to be repainted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I don't fully understand AutoLayout. Due to a [tip](https://alpha.app.net/mrtoto/post/4775059#4775004) from [Toto](https://alpha.app.net/mrtoto), I tried to test it under iOS 5 and  had to deactivate AutoLayout everywhere to run it.

It instantly worked with iOS 5. Afterwards I switched back to iOS 6 without activating AutoLayout again and it worked there perfectly too.

**My solution is: Deactivating AutoLayout in the XIB file(s).**

But I can't think of a way where this should be a default behavior. Maybe I miss a point of AutoLayout or this is a weird bug. As soon as I've talked to devs who are more into it, I'll probably submit a bugreport if necessary.

Comment: My experience has been that auto layout *is* a weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo on this line:

```
 CGRect viewFrame2 = self.viewThatShoudlDisappear1.frame;
```

Presumably, this should be:

```
 CGRect viewFrame2 = self.viewThatShoudlDisappear2.frame;
```

Comment: Thanks - edited it. I had to change the var names for reasons ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen odd things like this when I've accidentally used UIKit from a background thread.  UIKit should only be used from the main thread.